# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

I am creating a `WPF` application, which uses `PrincipleContext` to get the user `Guid` from the Active Directory.

Here's my code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
private string GetUserGuid()
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, getUsername());
    if (user != null)
    {
       return user.Guid.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       return string.Empty;
    }

 }
```

But the `PrincipalContext` throwing an `Exception`:

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException:
>   The server could not be contacted.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

maybe I'm a little bit late, but I had the same problem and I was looking for the answer. According to my tests this problem occurred when I didn't have internet connection or I wasn't in the same network that the domain of the machine. 
This was the key for me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the domain name in your `PrincipalContext`.

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

It should be:

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com");
```